# $f$ is one-to-one with domain $\mathbb{R} - \{ a\} $ implies range $\mathbb{R} - \{ b\} $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} - \{ a\}  \to \mathbb{R}$ be a one-to-one function ($a$ is real).

Does this imply that the range of $f$ is of the form $\mathbb{R} - \{ b\}$ ? ($b$ is real)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is a one-to-one function.

Comment: Is it also possible if  $f$ is required to be continuous in addition to being bijective?

Comment: If $f$ is a *continuous* one-to-one function, then the range of $f$ must be the union of two disjont open intervals.

Comment: @Unwisdom Thank you. I had a long day, could you please elaborate a bit? I know that continuous maps map connected sets to connected sets but it's not obvious to me this very second why this implies that they also have to map disconnected sets to disconnected sets.

Comment: @MattN. In general they don't.  For example, constant functions can take disconnected domains to connected (singleton) domains.  But in this case, we can use the fact that a continuous injection on a connected $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has to be monotone (because of the IVT). The result follows more or less directly from this observation.

Comment: @Unwisdom Thank you for your comment. I suppose the problem arises when, after mapping $(-\infty,a)$ to $(-\infty,a)$, one is forced to map $(a,\infty)$ to $[a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless you impose some extra constraints on $f$.  For example, let $a=0$ and let $f$ be the function:
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x-1 & \textrm{if }x\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\} \\ 
x & \textrm{otherwise} 
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then $f$ is actually a bijection (one-to-one and onto) from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all... the range of a one-to-one function like that can be any more than countable set. For example it could be: $[0,1]$, $\mathbb R$, a cantor set...

Comment: If the continuum hypothesis fails, then your answer is false.

Comment: This isn't quite right unless you assume the continuum hypothesis.  What is true is that the range of any one-to-one function must have cardinality equal to the continuum.

Comment: @Unwisdom you are right... that is what I meant. But the OP clearly doesn't know about cardinality, so we shouldn't mention it. I think instead that *countable* can be understood more easily. The example are however the real interesting point.